# CFC files don't open in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, coldfusion, cfeclipse

I installed eclipse oxygen and then CFEclipse and Subclipse using the "Eclipse Marketplace" like I have in past versions. With the current instal, when I open a cfc file in Eclipse, I get a red cross, with an error I'm gonna give you tonight when I'll be back home.

I'm posting this question now in the case other have already experienced this issue.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions relating code/programming

Comment: Does eclipse have "modes", such as design mode, code mode, etc?  If so, in what mode are your trying to open the file?

Comment: @angrykoala Stack Overflow is a site where you can ask questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers".  [Help Center > Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)